# ARM processors implementing ARMv5TE and VFPv1?

Tags: assembly, arm

Do there exist any ARM processors that implement the architecture version ARMv5TE (or ARMv5TEJ) yet also implement VFPv1 (as opposed to VFPv2)?

I am writing some assembly code for ARMv5TE and I would like to assume that if a VFP is present, it is VFPv2. Were there ever any processors shipped with this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no such processors.

> ·        **VFPv1** was implemented in the VFP10 revision 0 silicon (as provided by the ARM10200).  Support for this was deprecated in RVDS 2.1 and removed from RVDS 2.2 onwards.
>
> ·        **VFPv2** has been implemented in the VFP10 revision 1 (as provided by the ARM10200E), the VFP9-S (as available as a separately licensable option for ARM926/946/966) and the VFP11 (as provided in the ARM1136JF-S and ARM1176JZF-S).
>
> ·        **VFPv3** is backwards compatible with VFPv2 except that VFPv3 cannot trap floating-point exceptions and therefore requires no software support code. VFPv3 is implemented on ARM architecture v7 and later (e.g. Cortex-A8).

So, VFPv1 is implemented in ARM10200, which is ARMv5T ([ARM10200 Datasheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/ARM10200-datasheet.html), [ARM10200™ Reference Device Product Overview](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dvi0015a/index.html)). And only the next VFP10 revision (VPFv2) is available in ARMv5TE processors.

You can read more about VPF in [Application Note 133. **Using VFP with RVDS**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0133c/index.html)

Comment: This does cover processors made by ARM, but I think it would exclude other licensees possibly, like Qualcomm and Marvell. Still, I think it is likely there are so such processors.

Comment: This seems to definitely confirm now: http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/vector-floating-point.php